# Force JSONObject to JSONArray with one entry

Tags: android, json

I'm retrieving some `JSON` data from my server. Sometimes this can come in the form of a `JSONObject` (one objects) or a `JSONArray` (multiple objects). I'm aware of how to *detect* if it is an array or an object... but the problem is that detecting it means that I have to have two completely separate bits of logic, one for objects and one for arrays. It's a really unclean solution that I'm surprised is not asked about more often.

What I'd like to do is: if the `JSON` is a `JSONObject` (one object), then convert it to a `JSONArray` (with only one entry). Then I can proceed with my normal logic for interpreting `JSONArray`s.

My `JSON` would come in like this:

```
{
    "Changes":
    {
        "Row":
        {
            "@ChangeId":"17192386","@Type":"U","@TableName":"Change","@PK":"g1fbb6c7-abcf-e741-846c-b499baf5845d","@ColList":"date"
        },
        "Data":
        {
            "@date":"22/05/2014 09:03:00"
        }
    }
}
```

Normally I have multiple records in the `Row` and `Data` objects. But in this instance, I have only one in each. My usual method is:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject changes = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Changes");
JSONArray arrChanges = changes.getJSONArray("Row");
JSONArray arrData = changes.getJSONArray("Data");

// Cycle through arrays here
```

This code will crash on the `.getJSONArray("Row");` line.

To avoid this, after I have the `changes` object, I'd like to force the `Row` and `Data` objects into a `JSONArray`, even if there is only one value - like above, so I can continue with my normal logic. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you have to develop 2 different logic I think.

Comment: Can you show how your JSON with arrays would look like for the example? The description is a bit unclear about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this method to convert `JSONObject` into `JSONArray` :

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject changes = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Changes");
JSONArray arrChanges = covertJsonObjectToJsonArray(changes.get("Row"));
JSONArray arrData = covertJsonObjectToJsonArray(changes.get("Data"));


public  JSONArray covertJsonObjectToJsonArray(Object InsideArray) {

    JSONArray jsonArray;

    if (InsideArray instanceof JSONArray) {
        jsonArray = (JSONArray) InsideArray;
    } else {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put((JSONObject) InsideArray);
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

If `JSONArray` is there then it will return `JSONArray`,  and if `JSONOject` is there still it will return `JSONArray`.

Comment: Do I use this when creating the JSON array and saving it to a file, or when reading the file if it only has one object in the array?

Comment: @lindsaymacvean You can use this method while parsing json data if json array have more than one item , response will have jsonarray and if has only item it will json object. How can we manage this type of response in our code that  it will return jsonarray in both the case then we will use this method

Comment: Thanks @NeetuShrivastava I put some code that worked for me into an answer

Answer (score 2):

if I understood correctly what your problem is:

```
  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
  JSONObject changes = jsonObj.getJSONObject("Changes");
  JSONArray arrChanges = null;
  JSONArray arrData = null;
  if (isASingleJson) {
         arrChanges = new JSONArray();
         arrData = new JSONArray();
         arrChanges.put(changes.getJSONObject("Row"));
         arrData.put(changes.getJSONObject("Data"));
  } else {
         arrChanges = changes.getJSONArray("Row");
         arrData = changes.getJSONArray("Data");
  }
  //logic to handle arrays here...
```

Comment: +1 a good solution. I had to accept Neetu's answer as it was slightly cleaner, but your answer helped me understand json a little better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating your JSON you shouldcreate an array of "Row" items always, even if you have only one. This way you will not have to change any logic.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Create on Json Array, 
when data from server is array then go with that same flow 
but if you get data from server in Object format then just create object and add that object again into same Array 
so You need to write logic only to parse Array in any of the case.

I hope you get my point.
Happy Coddddiiiing :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to AMC's answer I constructed the following methods to create a JSON object, store it in a file on the android device. Then if only a single object was stored then the read file method uses the convertJsonObjectToJsonArray to convert it back to an array when reading it.

```
public void createFile(View v) throws IOException, JSONException {
    JSONArray tours = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject tour;
    tour = new JSONObject();
    tour.put("name", "Sea and sand");
    tour.put("price", 999);
    tours.put(tour);
    String text = tour.toString();
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("tours", MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(text.getBytes());
    fos.close();
    UIHelper.displayText(this, R.id.textView1, "File written to disk:\n"+text);
}

public void readFile(View v) throws IOException, JSONException {
    // read file to Buffered input stream
    FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("tours");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    while (bis.available() != 0) {
        char c = (char) bis.read();
        b.append(c);
    }
    bis.close();
    fis.close();
    // deserialize JSON object to text
    JSONObject tours = new JSONObject(b.toString());
    // If a single object is returned convert it to an Array
    JSONArray toursArray = convertJsonObjectToJsonArray(tours);
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < toursArray.length(); i++) {
        String tour = toursArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
        text.append(tour).append("\n");
    }
    UIHelper.displayText(this, R.id.textView1, text.toString());
}

public  JSONArray convertJsonObjectToJsonArray(Object InsideArray) {
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    if (InsideArray instanceof JSONArray) {
        jsonArray = (JSONArray) InsideArray;
    } else {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        jsonArray.put((JSONObject) InsideArray);
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```